# Produce Generalised Hamming Numbers Python

Tags: python, number-theory

This is my code to generate all the Hamming Numbers (aka 5-smooth-Numbers) under a given limit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number

> In number theory, a smooth (or friable) number is an integer which factors completely into small prime numbers. For example, a 7-smooth number is a number whose prime factors are all at most 7, so 49 = 7^2 and 15750 = 2 × 32 × 53 × 7 are both 7-smooth, while 11 and 702 = 2 × 33 × 13 are not

I know of other ways to generate the numbers, however the function I first made makes sense to me and was wondering how to expand this to 7-smooth, 11-smooth, ..., n-smooth-numbers. Is there a simpler way to change my function to loop through the primes below the limit without adding lines of very similar code?

```
import math

def HammingFiveUnder(limit):
    hammings = []
    exp2 = int(math.log(limit, 2))
    exp3 = int(math.log(limit, 3))
    exp5 = int(math.log(limit, 5))
    for i in range(0, exp2+1):
        for j in range(0, exp3+1):
            for k in range(0, exp5+1):
                poss_ham = 2**i * 3**j * 5**k
                if poss_ham <= limit:
                    hammings.append(poss_ham)
    return sorted(hammings)

print(HammingFiveUnder(100))
```

Comment: Why not the other way around: look for the prime number decomposition of numbers below the limit, and filter out those with the too large prime factor?

Comment: Finding the prime factorization for all the numbers is a computationally hard problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the same logic, you just need to make use of more suitable data types and [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from the standard library.

`itertools.product` will give you all combinations of the list items so it's equivalent to the nested loops.

```
import itertools

# returns (n,p) as n**p
def tuplePower(t):
  n, p = t
  return n**p

# returns the product of the list items
def multiplyIter(myIter):
  result = 1
  for i in myIter:
    result = result * i
  return result

def HammingFiveUnder(limit):
  hammings = []
  # iterable data structures
  multipliers = (2, 3, 5)
  exps = [int(math.log(limit, x)) for x in multipliers]
  # compose the list of ranges to replace nested for loops
  ranges_lists = [[i for i in range(0, n+1)] for n in exps]
  combo_list = list(itertools.product(*ranges_lists))
  # iterate through the list
  for combo_item in combo_list:
    poss_ham = multiplyIter(list(map(tuplePower, zip(multipliers, combo_item))))
    if poss_ham <= limit:
      hammings.append(poss_ham)
  return sorted(hammings)

print(HammingFiveUnder(100))
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different solution using the Cartesian product [`itertool.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function:

> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

`n_primes` is the number of prime factor wanted taken in order.

```
from itertools import product as cartesianproduct # Cartesian product of input iterables.
from functools import reduce
import math

def prod(list_of_numbers):
    ''' Compute the product of the given numbers '''
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, list_of_numbers)

def smoothnumbers(n_primes=3, limit=100):
    # List of the primes numbers:
    primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41]

    # Compute the possible exponent ranges given the limit:
    max_exponents = [math.floor(math.log(limit, prime))
                     for prime in primes[:n_primes]]
    exponents_ranges = [range(max_exp+1) for max_exp in max_exponents]

    # loop
    smoothnumbers = []
    for exponents in cartesianproduct(*exponents_ranges):
        n = prod( factor**exp for factor, exp in zip(primes, exponents) )
        # print(exponents, n)
        if n <= limit:
            smoothnumbers.append(n)

    return sorted(smoothnumbers)
```

Which gives:

```
print( smoothnumbers(n_primes=2, limit=100) )
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24, 27, 32, 36, 48, 54, 64, 72, 81, 96]

print( smoothnumbers(n_primes=3, limit=100) )
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27, 30, 32, 36,
#  40, 45, 48, 50, 54, 60, 64, 72, 75, 80, 81, 90, 96, 100]

print( smoothnumbers(n_primes=5, limit=100) )
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25,
#  27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 40, 42, 44, 45, 48, 49, 50, 54, 55, 56, 60, 63,
#  64, 66, 70, 72, 75, 77, 80, 81, 84, 88, 90, 96, 98, 99, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to make a list of all possible primes, then computer all combination using `itertools.combinations` and multiply the elements of each of those lists. I had to filter out all the double combinations, so there is still some potential for a speed boost.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import itertools

def HammingFiveUnder(limit):
    hammings = []

    def prime_list():
        '''create a list with primes repeated as many times as they can maximally occur under the said limit in a prime factorisation'''
        list_with_repeated_primes = []   
        for prime in [2,3,5,7]: #change this for smooth number you want
            rep = int(math.log(limit, prime))
            for n in range(rep):
                list_with_repeated_primes.append(prime)
        return list_with_repeated_primes
    list_with_repeated_primes = prime_list()

#now make all possible combinations of primes and check against limit:
    comb = []
    for i in range(len(list_of_repeated_primes)):
        comb += itertools.combinations(list_of_repeated_primes,i+1)
    comb = np.unique(comb)
    for i in comb:
        poss_ham = np.prod(np.array(i))  
        if poss_ham <= limit:
            hammings.append(poss_ham)
    return sorted(hammings)

print(HammingFiveUnder(100))
```